# Drive File Stream - proxy

Tags: google-drive-api

I've discovered that file stream doesn't play nicely with network or host proxy or security solutions. Had to disable them to get file stream working. Found a note buried in an article that there is a way to start file stream with path to the proxy certificates, but I can't find instructions on how to do this."Drive File Stream encrypts all network traffic and validates host certificates to protect against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. If you deploy to a network that uses a decrypting proxy, you may need to start Drive File Stream with this option:--trusted_root_certs_file="Can you provide instructions on how to configure Mac and PC clients to start File Stream with this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to run a command to set the proxy settings:

The command that I used in cmd was:

"C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\25.1.63.1725\GoogleDriveFS.exe" --trusted_root_certs_file="C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\25.1.63.1725\config\roots.pem"

where "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\25.1.63.1725\config\roots.pem"
is the certificate file of the proxy server.

Comment: What is my firewall doesn’t use a security certificate?

Comment: This did not help for me, and I can I see in the log file that Google File Stream uses that certificate per default.